# How to pass output of command to sed

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, sed

My **sed** command in **#Update key in config file.**  does not get the contents of the variable **$GETKEY**
Someone help me?

```
  # Get key from output of the website.
  GETKEY=`wget https://www.badips.com/get/key -qO - | awk {'print $9'} | cut -d ":" -f3 | cut -d "}" -f1 | sed 's/\"//g'`
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]
  then

      # Update key in config file.    
      sed -i 's/^\(KEY\s*=\s*\).*$/\1$GETKEY/' Config

  fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables do not get substituted within single quotes. Use:

```
  sed -ri "s/^(KEY\\s*=\\s*).*$/\\1$GETKEY/" Config
```

I used `-r` to remove the need to escape the parentheses, but the other backslashes need to be escaped within single quotes. Otherwise, you can mix quotes:

```
  sed -ri 's/^(KEY\s*=\s*).*$/\1'"$GETKEY/" Config
```